# WPF UI freeze after showing winforms controls

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, block, freeze

I have the problem, that when i open a wpf window which embed some Winforms controls, my WPF application seems to freeze after pressing some buttons in the winforms control. The curious thing is, that i can click on buttons and interact with the UI, but their is no button hilight or other UI feedback. It is hard to describe, but on the one hand the UI works, but on the other hand the visual part of the UI seems not to be updated.

I can reproduce the same problem, if lock windows via Ctrl + Alt + Del and unlocking during the application is running.

If i press Ctrl + Alt + Break to see where the process is, i will always return at `.Run(mainWindow);`.

Maybe some one has a solution for my problem, thank you

Comment: Currently i try to rebuild the error in a small application. It is not very easy to extract the problem, because the complete application is a lot ok code... over 300K lines...

Comment: I noticed a problem with the win form host control before; due to it's nature it doesn't really integrate in wpf ui. The issue I had was a problem with the Z-order of the host container: it was always on top of my other wpf components. You might want to check if it is related. While trying to fix that all kind of errors occurred so we abandoned the idea.

Comment: A Z-Order problem also seems to appear, how to you have solved it?

Comment: We removed winform-host container and rebuild-ed it in xaml :-|

Comment: Ok, that is not possible in my case, because the WinForm-Controls are 3rd party controls...